# Fill-up C# struct from C

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I have the following C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct DATA
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
};
```

I also have a variable of this struct type called `my_data` filled-up with some values:

```
DATA my_data;

my_data.x = 10;
my_data.y = 12;
```

I can successfully pass this variable (by pinning it, get its real address and use P/Invoke) to a C program (built for this purpose) and, from this program, get values `10` and `12`.

Now, I am trying to multiply each of these two values by `2` and populate the C# struct (from C) with the result of these multiplications but without success. How can this be done?

***EDIT***

If instead of a `struct` I have a `class` it works fine:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class DATA
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the code described in your last two paragraphs?  It helps us help you if we have a [mcve].

Comment: You need to add results to the structure in both c and c#.  Before you call the c program you are using Marshal to copy from managed memory to unmanged memory.  After returning you have to copy the unmanaged memory back to managed memory to get the results in c#.

Comment: If it works fine for class, but not for struct, there is chance that you changed a copy of struct, because structs are value types @user7698505 Please, show us how did you multiply them

Comment: @jdweng Could you please elaborate a bit further? I can successfully read the values (set in C#) from C without issues (by using the real address of the C# variable). Why it does not work the way around (i.e. write some values to the C# struct from C).

Comment: C# structs have overhead so it might be undefined behavior. Probably best not to pass address of structs between C and C#

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks for your comment. The fact that 1) I can read the values shows that I'm using the correct the address of the variable and 2) the C code is correctly multiplying values since when using a `class` (instead of `struct`) the final result (i.e. multiplication) is correct. What am I missing here?

Comment: The structure is passed from c# to c on the execution stack.  When you return from the method the stack is not valid so any memory allocated locally in the c method is no longer valid.  So you must allocate the memory for the structure before calling the method so the data is valid when you return.

Comment: @jdweng Got it! But why is then that I can read the values from C but not write new values? It sounds strange because the address of variable `my_data` (of type struct `DATA`) didn't change since it's pinned.

Comment: As I said the stack is not longer valid and was reused.  Other data probably overwritten the data that you wrote.

Comment: @jwdeng: but why it is overwritten in the first place? There is apparently no reason for this since the only thing that is passed to C is the address (i.e. a number returned by `handle = GCHandle.Alloc(my_data, GCHandleType.Pinned); address = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();`) of variable `my_data`. In fact, the variable continues to have the same values (like the multiplication that took place in C never existed). If it was overwritten (like you wrote) then one would have expected random/garbage values in `my_data`.

Comment: The stack frame holding the arguments (parameter values) gets popped when the function call returns. If you’re passing the arguments by value instead of a reference or pointer, then you’re dealing with copies of the struct rather than the original struct itself. It would have helped to see a code example which shows what your code actually looks like. Otherwise we can only speculate.

Comment: Ok, so how do I copy it back ?